# Why does iCloud have a different timezone for my calendar events than my devices do?

Tags: ical, ios, icloud

I set an appointment on iCal from 19:30 to 22:00. In the iCloud calendar it shows as 18:30 to 21:00. In iCal on Macbook Pro, on iPhone 4S and iPad 2 it shows the correct time i.e. 19:30 to 22:00!

I have timezone support switched off and I have the UK as the timezone. How can it be that iCloud (where the devices get the times from) is showing incorrect times, yet all the devices are showing the correct time?

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Each of your devices has a timezone setting, which you probably already set correctly.

What you probably didn't know is that iCloud.com has its own timezone setting. To access it, login to icloud.com, then click on your name in the upper right corner. Once set, you should see everything ok.

The “time zone support” setting you disabled has to do with creating *events* associated with a timezone, and is usually better left off.

NOTE: Once you change this you will have to logout and then login again for the changes to take effect.